# How to append functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I would like to know how to make something like `someClass.firstFunction(...).sencondFunction(...).maybeThirdOne(...)`
I'm using Node.js and trying to build something like this:

```
class Request {
    constructor() {
        this.query = '';
        this.data = [];
    }

    connenct() {
        // connect to the DB
    }

    query(query) {
        // define my sql statement
    }

    get() {
        // fire the requst and set this.data
    }

    onlyFirst() {
        // get first item from this.data
    }

    modifyTheDataSomeHow() {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

when I call `request.connect().('select * from table').get()` I should get the data 
and when I call `request.connect().('select * from table').get().onlyFirst()` I should get only first item.

My goal is to know generally how something like this could work like 
`someClass.firstFunction(...).sencondFunction(...).maybeThirdOne(...)`

or by another call

`someClass.firstFunction(...).sencondFunction(...).sometimesForthOne(...)`

Answer (score 1):

This is called function/method chaining. It generally revolves around returning an instance of `this` at the end. Here's a simple example to demonstrate ([source](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/understanding-method-chaining-in-javascript-647a9004bd4f)):

```js
class Chainable {
  firstMethod() {
    console.log('This is the First Method');
    return this;
  }
  
  secondMethod() {
    console.log('This is the Second Method');
    return this;
  }
  
  thirdMethod() {
    console.log('This is the Third Method');
    return this;
  }
}

const chainableInstance = new Chainable()
chainableInstance
  .firstMethod()
  .secondMethod()
  .thirdMethod();

// Console Output
// This is the First Method
// This is the Second Method
// This is the Third Method
```

You may modify to do something similarly, for example:

```
class Request {
    constructor() {
        this.query = '';
        this.data = [];
    }

    query(query) {
        this.query = query;
        // now you can chain methods off since we're returning the same object back
        return this;
    }
    get() {
        // perform query here
        this.data = retrievedData;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the functions are async and inside them I'm doing await calls like:
@rb612
```class Chainable {
  async firstMethod() {
    const text = await somthing.getText();
    return this;
  }
  
  async secondMethod() {
    console.log('This is the Second Method');
    return this;
  }
  
  async thirdMethod() {
    console.log('This is the Third Method');
    return this;
  }
}```

Comment: Because `async` functions return promises, if, say, all 3 methods in the example were declared `async`, you could do `myChainable.firstMethod().then((obj) => obj.secondMethod()).then(obj => obj.thirdMethod())`. Promises are chained already like this, so you would get the functionality you expect.

Answer (score -1):

May be `javascript prototype` can help you. You can create multi-layer prototype to do it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the relevant parts instead of posting a link as they may expire or get changed. Moreover, the link you provided doesn't answer the question OP has asked.